# webpack Module not found issue

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm new in Webpack (before I used Gulp) and now I want to move the existing application from Gulp to Webpack.

But I'm getting issues like Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/src/app/index.js' in '/var/www/project' or `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/src/styles/main.scss' in '/var/www/project'` and same for every file i'm using on my enty chain.

Here is my file structures:

- package.json
- .env
- .env.example
- webpack.conf.js
- src/

  - app/

    - index.js
    - other js/vue related files
  - styles/

    - main.scss and all related styles
  - public/

    - index.html
    - favicon.ico
    - images/

      - all images

and here is mine `webpack.conf.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const ENV = process.env.APP_ENV;
const isDev = ENV === 'dev'
const isProd = ENV === 'prod';
function setDevTool() {
  if (isDev) {
    return 'inline-source-map';
  } else if (isProd) {
    return 'source-map';
  } else {
    return 'eval-source-map';
  }
}
const config = {
  entry: {
    'bundle.min.css': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/styles/main.scss'),
    ],
    'bundle.js': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/app/index.js')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devtool: setDevTool(),
  module: {
    rules: [
      // fonts loader
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'fonts/'
        }
      },
      // babel loader
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/
        ]
      },
      // raw html loader
      {
        test: /\.html/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
      // css loader
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      },
      // sass loader
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      // vue loader
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      // image url inliner
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 50 * 1024
        }
      },
      // svg url inliner
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-url-loader',
        options: {

          limit: 50 * 1024,
          noquotes: true,
        }
      },
      // image loader
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
        enforce: 'pre'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + "/src/public/index.html",
      inject: 'body'
    }),
    new Dotenv({safe: true}),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.min.css"),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src',
    port: 7700,
  }
}

if (isProd) {
  config.plugins.push(
    new UglifyJSPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: __dirname + '/src/public'
    }])
  );
};
module.exports = config;
```

I do not understand why it can't find those files if for examlpe '/var/www/project//src/styles/main.scss' it mention in error is correct path?

Comment: Do you have tried remove initial slash? i.e. `/src/styles/main.scss`!

Comment: you are right, looks like it helped, thanks! The configuration example I use as a reference also has trailing slashes. Now I have other errors, but it's another story. Create the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Nice to hear that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the initial slashes from `path.resolve()`. For example:

`path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/styles/main.scss')`

should be:

`path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/main.scss')`